# we have the CSV / SSV. What are the | separated values called?

Tags: validation, csv, data-transfer, data-tracing

we have the CSV for comma-separated-values / SSV for semi-colon-seperated-values.

So what is the name for a | separated value?

Btw what even is the name for thhe | symbol? (i remember its a pipe, but i think that's just an unofficial name or smt)

Comment: According to wikipedia it's called a vertical bar, and has many other names: Sheffer stroke (in logic), verti-bar, vbar, stick, vertical line, vertical slash, bar, pike, or pipe...

Comment: `|` might have many names but I have only heard programmers call it “bar” or “pipe”.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general form is known as DSV - see http://www.catb.org/~esr/writings/taoup/html/ch05s02.html.

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly known as *PSV* for *pipe-separated-values*.